# My algorithm should search Binary but i dont why it doenst work

Tags: algorithm, scala, binary-search

My binarySearch algorithm doesnt work. Can you help me ?

It should find target value from the given sorted array values.
If the value could not be found, return None

```
def binarySearch(values: Array[Int], target: Int): Option[Int] = {
    val n = values.size
    var left = 0
    var right = n - 1
    while(left <= right){
      val mid = (left + right) / 2
      val value = values(mid)
      if(value == target)
        return Some(mid)
      else if(value < target)
        right = mid
      else
        left = mid
    }
    None
  }
```

Comment: How do you mean it doesn't work? What are your test conditions, expected results, actual results?

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: For reference, the 2.13 scala library provides a binary search in [IndexedSeq.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/IndexedSeq.scala#L96)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code suffers from a number of problems.

First off, the `while` loop condition, `left <= right`, is **always** true. The value of `mid = (left+right)/2` can never adjust `left` or `right` such that `left > right`.

There's an easy fix for this: `while (left < right)`. But this unfortunately creates 2 exit results, the target can't be found **or** the target is the final value, so we need to test for that after exiting the `while` loop.

```
if (values(left) == target) Some(left) else None
```

The next problem is that you're adjusting the wrong variable for current `mid` value. The simple fix is to change from `if(value < target)` to `if(value > target)`.

Also, after you know that `mid` is not the target we're looking for, it doesn't have to be retained for any future grouping. So now that section looks like this:

```
else if(value > target)
  right = mid-1
else
  left = mid+1
```

Finally, your code doesn't handle the empty array condition. Let's add that test at the end.

```
if (n > 0 && values(left) == target) Some(left) else None
```

So now the code passes all the tests that I've thrown at it. Unfortunately it's still an ugly hodgepodge of mutable variables and imperative programming. Not the clean FP Scala style we like to see.

Here's a possible alternative worth considering.

```
def binarySearch(values :Array[Int], target :Int) :Option[Int] = {
  def bs(lo :Int, hi :Int) :Option[Int] = {
    val mid = (lo + hi)/2
    target compare values(mid) match {
      case  0             => Some(mid)    //found
      case _ if mid == lo => None         //can't be found
      case -1             => bs(lo, mid)  //lower half
      case  1             => bs(mid, hi)  //upper half
    }
  }
  values.headOption.flatMap(_ => bs(0, values.length))
}
```

testing:

```
val arr = Array(1,2,3,5,6)
binarySearch(arr,0)               //res0: Option[Int] = None
binarySearch(arr,1)               //res1: Option[Int] = Some(0)
binarySearch(arr,2)               //res2: Option[Int] = Some(1)
binarySearch(arr,3)               //res3: Option[Int] = Some(2)
binarySearch(arr,4)               //res4: Option[Int] = None
binarySearch(arr,5)               //res5: Option[Int] = Some(3)
binarySearch(arr,6)               //res6: Option[Int] = Some(4)
binarySearch(arr,7)               //res7: Option[Int] = None
binarySearch(Array.empty[Int],8)  //res8: Option[Int] = None
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the working code

```
def binarySearch(arr: Array[Int], left: Int, right: Int, target: Int) {


    if (right >= left)
        var mid = int((left + right) / 2)

        if (arr[mid] == target)
            return mid

        else if (arr[mid] < target)
            return binarySearch(arr, mid+1, right, target)

        else if (arr[mid] > target):
            return binarySearch(arr, left, mid-1, target)
    else:
        return -1
}
```